# Python - how to authenticate consult Google Analytics from AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, google-analytics, google-oauth, aws-lambda

I have a python script to consult certain data from Google Analytics but im trying to go a little bit further and let Lambda (from amazon web services) do it automatically for me everyday. But i encounter a problem and im stuck with it.

I don't know how can i authenticate OAuth 2.0 from the script without using a client_secrets.json file and if there is no other way to do it how and where i should leave the .json file in order to let it authenticate itself.

As it explains [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts) since im not using one of google services i need to use:

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
'/path/to/keyfile.json', scopes)
```

but i have no path for the file.

Comment: Do you have the `keyfile.json` in your zip? It should just be in the working directory.

Comment: I dont follow, i have the keyfile but idk where im sopposed to drop it on aws and what to enter in the path for the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check out the docs for `ServiceAccountCredentials` at https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.service_account.html#oauth2client.service_account.ServiceAccountCredentials

you'll see that as well as `.from_json_keyfile_name` there is a constructor `from_json(json_data)`. That should do what you need.