# OAuth 2 - Authenticate with JSON file without directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-analytics, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, aws-lambda

So im trying to set up un lambda from amazon web services a javascript that consults data from google analytics and drops it on a S3 Bucket, so far the script works fine since im authenticating with a client_secrets.json from my computer but now that im trying to do it from lambda i cant figure out how can i copy&paste the JSON content into the script and use it in order to authenticate? The main issue is that is should be able to authenticate itself without human intervention.

[image: example]

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44975002/python-how-to-authenticate-consult-google-analytics-from-aws-lambda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code i show above if you remove the *from_json()* and just leave the *json_data* it would work just fine, hope it helps.